# Building libcurl yields "Unsupported Protocol" at runtime for HTTPS

Tags: ssl, curl, libcurl

I am working on rebuilding libcurl for our application but am encountering the following problem at runtime (libcurl builds fine):

> [20:03:24] WARNING: API call failed: cURL Error in putStatus(): Unsupported protocol

(the output is from our code, "`Unsupported protocol`" is from curl)

Now you would think this is just a matter of curl not being built with `SSL` support, however the end of our configure statement clearly states that it is:

```
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.29.0
  Host setup:       armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
```

> [snip]
>     Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTMP RTSP SCP SFTP SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

Any pointers on why our curl might be behaving this way?

Comment: Did you copy the ssl libraries to the target?  You can verify with `strace` and `ldd` what the libraries are that curl is trying to load.